# MySQL Get exactly one entry per id by multiple ids

Tags: mysql

my problem is that I want this:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE userId = 7243
ORDER BY date desc LIMIT 1
```

But for multiple ids in one request.
I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE userId IN (7243, 1)
GROUP BY userId
ORDER BY date desc
```

But the order by seems to be ignored. Do anyone has a solution for me? Thank you

Comment: What is the expected result after group by? When you add `GROUP BY userId` you will get one row for each user 1 and 7243. All other columns will contain data for arbitrary row for that user. That explains why you get an unexpected date.

Comment: Using `SELECT * ... GROUP BY column` is common error when using MySQL. MySQL has a extended GROUP BY "feature" which allows you to use non-aggregated columns in the select which are not not the GROUP BY clause only problem is that ever non non-aggregated column which is not in the select can have unrelated data unless could have used functional dependency.. The most modern MySQL versions (i believe it's around 5.5+) has a sql mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY which stops this bad feature..

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the max date record for each of the two IDs, then you may use a subquery:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT userId, MAX(date) AS max_date
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE userId IN (7243, 1)
    GROUP BY userId
) t2
   ON t1.userId = t2.userId AND t1.date = t2.max_date
WHERE
    t1.userId IN (7243, 1);
```

This is the just greatest-value-per-group question with a slight twist, namely that you only want to see two of the possible groups in the output.

As @Raymond commented below, an index on `(userId, date)` should greatly speed up the `t2` subquery.  I am not sure if this index would help beyond that, but it should make a difference.

Comment: Does it work better if you repeat the where clause in the outer query?

Comment: "Does it work better if you repeat the where clause in the outer query? " Might generate a beter query plan for the "outer" sql @SalmanA

Comment: "It works, but the query is too slow now " You need a index @Amannti The multi column index  `userId, date` should work fine with this query... "an index on (userId, date) should greatly speed up the t2 subquery. I am not sure if this index would help beyond that" The index might/should also help the `ON t1.userId = t2.userId AND t1.date = t2.max_date
WHERE
    t1.userId IN (7243, 1);` part off the query..